# explicit conformal map of sinus-shaped region

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables

I wonder weather an explicit conformal map of a sinus-shaped region given by  $\Re(z) \in [0, 1+\delta \sin(\Im(z)) ]$ onto say a strip or a ball is known (of course $0<\delta < 1$). Thank you.

Comment: Explicit conformal maps can almost never be given; why would you expect one here? The answer is highly likely to be "no", but good estimates can be given about the behaviour of the conformal map if required.